# How to read List of Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to read the data from a list that has the data of **Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'**.

In the below code I am trying to get the data from DB

```
getData() async {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    var categoryList = [];
    db.collection('categories')
        .doc(value)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var listSubCol = doc["categoryCollection"];
      listSubCol.forEach((id) {
        db.collection('categories')
            .doc(value)
            .collection(id)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) {
          categoryList.add(snapshot);
          return categoryList;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Below is the code where I am printing the values.

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Something went wrong");
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                print('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
                return Text("Text");
              }
              return Text("Text Outside");
            }
        )
```

I got a null value.

Can anyone please help me with how to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  getData() async {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await db.collection('categories').doc(value).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var listSubCol = doc["categoryCollection"];
      listSubCol.forEach((id) {
        db.collection('categories').doc(value).collection(id).get().then((snapshot) {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
            categoryList.add(element.data());
          });
        });
        return categoryList;
      });
    });
    return categoryList;
  }
```

using the above method i got the data from Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

The getData is a `Future<void>`, so when the FutureBuilder is completed the snapshot.data is always null.

Change getData to return a List of whatever you are getting.

```
Future<List<Categories>> getData() async {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final List<Categories> categoryList = [];
    await db.collection('categories')
        .doc(value)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var listSubCol = doc["categoryCollection"];
      listSubCol.forEach((id) {
        db.collection('categories')
            .doc(value)
            .collection(id)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) {
          categoryList.add(snapshot);
          return categoryList;
        });
      });
    });
    return categoryList;
  }
```

Comment: I am getting this error The argument type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CategoryModel'.

Comment: Try this: `Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {`

Comment: Now i am getting this error The argument type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CategoryModel'

Comment: There is a type mismatch in the object coming from the firestore. I suggest to use  "custom objects" to facilitate. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Comment: Ok, i will check